Why is "that" omitted after "whatever" in this sentence?
Here's a direct quote from a news article:

(They should) quickly cut whatever deals are necessary to satisfy a key constituency that has, justifiably, felt ignored in recent years.

This reads ungrammatical to me, as the relative pronoun "that" is omitted even though it is not the object of the clause.

(They should) quickly cut whatever deals that are necessary to satisfy a key constituency that has, justifiably, felt ignored in recent years.

Is this an error?

It has not been omitted.
We would say 'the deals that are necessary' if it was perfectly clear and well-known what those deals were.
Using whatever indicates that the writer doesn't know which ones are necessary, just that some probably are. The sentence doesn't require that as well.

Can you elaborate on why "that" is not needed here? It seems to me "whatever(ADJ) deals(NOUN) that are necessary" makes more sense as a relative clause?

I was almost able to convince myself that including the superfluous that here was something that might have been more common a century or two ago. But as this chart shows, it never had any currency. Note that I switched OP's deals + necessary to things + true - the same basic construction, but with more common words...

...where whatever things that are true doesn't occur often enough to show on the usage chart, so there's the link to the only two instances of that sequence in the entire Google Books corpus.

There's no question that many that's, such as my earlier I was almost able to convince myself [that] including..., are completely optional. Include them or not, as you see fit. But sometimes, they're necessary - and apparently some other times they're positively unwanted.

@oeter: It's because whatever is not a "determiner", like Those / the / any things that are necessary will be provided. I'm not sure how to deconstruct Such things as are necessary will be provided - but that's another different context, along with whatever, where you can't reasonably introduce the relativizer that.

@FumbleFingers If whatever is not a determiner, is it a pronoun? Given whatever is immediately followed by deals, I think it can't be a pronoun. Or in this case whatever deals together serve as pronoun? I can think of two examples that read right: 1) "You should do whatever makes you feel good."  2) " You should do whatever thing that makes you feel good." But "You should do whatever thing makes you feel good" just doesn't sound right to me.

@FumbleFingers - ...And the Bible verse quoted in your Google results seems to be a misquotation; none of the versions shown here have things that.

@oeter: I'm not much interested in assigning "part of speech" labels in "difficult" contexts, and (probably precisely because of that attitude) I find a lot of words difficult to categorise. But In our current context, whatever is just an emphatic version of what, which so far as I'm concerned is the same as  that which here. As in What / Whatever / That which is useful is expensive, where you can introduce an explicit noun (such as thing) after the first two but not the last (because that before which is a pronoun standing for thing anyway).


whatever deals are necessary

This is the fused relative construction (or "free" or "headless" relative construction), where whatever is a determinative. Some related examples—that is optional with whatever (it cannot go with plain what):

Pronoun what(ever)

I will eat what you cook.
I will eat whatever you cook.
I will eat whatever that you cook. (informal?)


Determinative what(ever)

I will eat what food you cook.
I will eat whatever food you cook.
I will eat whatever food that you cook.



This construction with determinative what is discussed on p. 291 of Student's Introduction to English Grammar, 2nd edition.

whatever deals are necessary would be classified as an interrogative content clause (like an embedded question), similar to what deals are necessary.  In such a wh-clause, that would be otiose and ungrammatical.
ever in whatever expresses the meaning "of any kind"; as Kate says in her answer, the speaker is leaving that open to the situation since the extent and nature of the deals may not be known at the time the words were spoken (or written).
Check out this site, as it may help, even though it uses somewhat different nomenclature:

... it’s impossible to include a complementizer in embedded content questions in English—or at least, we can conclude that it’s impossible in my variety of English, and very likely in yours as well.

